# Code for finding largest product of 13 consecutive digits of a 1000 digit number does not give required output

Tags: python, list

The code is to find the largest possible product of 13 consecutive digits of a 1000 digit number. When I tried to run it on IDLE, it just gave RESTART and the directory where I saved the .py file. When I tried this on Pycharm(I know its not the IDE's problem, but I just had to try), no output. Am I doing something wrong?

```
n=7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
s=[]
j=13
def product(j):
    p = 1
    for i in range(j,j+13):
        p=p*s[i]
    return(p)
for i in range(0,1000):
    s=s+[n%10]
    n=n//10
k = product(0)
c=k
while j<1000:
    if s[j]==0:
        j=j+1
        c=product(j)
        while c==0:
            j=j+13
            c=product(j)       
    else:
        c=(c*s[j+13])/s[j]   
    if c>k:
        k=c
print(k)
```

Comment: Please extract a [mcve], which in particular includes reducing `n` to a human-manageable value. Also, as a new user, take the tour and read [ask], it explains a few other things missing. That said, learn how to step through the code with a debugger, which will help you to selve the problem yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. However, the bad variable names, lack of comments in your code, and your unusual approach make it very difficult to understand what you are doing and what you are trying to do. Style matters a great deal in making code easier for other programmers (and for yourself in a few month's time) to understand.

Comment: Would expect you to get a list index out of bounds exception in places where you index into [j+13] in the code since j goes up to 999, but there are only 1000 digits in the number (i.e. list s).  Thus, rather than 'j<1000', should have 'j<1000-13'.  You can develop the code using a smaller size number (such as 15 digits) to more easily debug what's happening.  Perhaps also use a variable for the number of digits rather than hardcoding 1000.

Comment: Problem is your code is in an infinite loop since you don't increment j in the while loop for the case s[j] != 0.  If you do increment j after line 'c=(c*s[j+13])/s[j]' you get a 'index out of range' error when j gets to 987.  Thus, as mentioned earlier j should go only to 1000-13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code can be simplified to the following.

```
n=7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

def product(j):
    p = 1
    for i in range(j,j+13):
        p=p*s[i]
    return(p)
s=[]
for i in range(0,1000):
    s=s+[n%10]
    n=n//10
k = 0
N = len(s)
j = 0
while j<N-13:  #need to 13 elements before end
    c = product(j)
    if c>k:
        k=c
    j = j + 1
print(k)
```

Result: 23514624000
This can be generated more easily even without resorting to Numpy by:

```
digits = str(n) # generates digits of number
products = [product(j) for j in range(1000-13)] # list comprehension
                                                # uses you product function
print(max(products))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> n=7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
>>> digits = str(n)
>>> from numpy import prod
>>> products = [prod( map( int, digits[i:i+13])) for i in range(len(digits)-13)] 
>>> max(products)
23514624000
```

Here's the quick explanation. First line -- this is your number. Second line -- I convert the number (like, 123) into the string "123", so I can take it digit by digit, hence the name of the variable `digits`.

I'm lazy to write multiplication routine, so I use a ready-made from `numpy` package, it's called `prod` and computes a product of the list, for example, `prod( [1,2,3] ) = 6`.

The next line is kind of complicated, but all it does -- going over your digits, selecting 13 of them at at time (`digits[i:i+13]`) and multiply them, saving the results in `products`.

Finally, the last line finds the maximum number in the `products`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "source_file.py", line 5, in <module>
    max(products)
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'map' and 'map'
*I'm getting this error*

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "source_file.py", line 5, in <module>
    max(products)
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'map' and 'map'

Comment: ok, strange version of python detected =)  Please, replace `max(products)` with `max(list(products))` -- this should work

Comment: did you import `prod` from `numpy` and did you use it in the line `products = [ prod( .... ) ]` ? there can't be instances of `map()` anywhere, because they are supposed to be wrapped by `prod( ... )`

Comment: I just copied your code directly and added the max modification. I just started with Python. I don't really understand your code

Comment: added explanation. hope this helps